# How to set the background color of navigation tab in android

Tags: android

How to set the background color of navigation tab in android with this kind of code. `

```
            ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
            bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            ActionBar.Tab tab1 = bar.newTab();
            ActionBar.Tab tab2 = bar.newTab();
            tab1.setText("Fragment A");
            tab2.setText("Fragment B");
            tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
            tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
            bar.addTab(tab1);
            bar.addTab(tab2);`
```

i did not create a tab in xml. i was just wondering if its possible in this kind of code. thank you.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842418/how-to-draw-on-actionbar-tab-when-using-actionbarsherlock-in-android

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to style the tab background by changing tabbar style from res/values/themes.xml? Here is a sample for Theme.Sherlock.Light theme.

```
<style name="Theme.test" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Theme.test.tabbar.style</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Widget.test.ActionBar.TabBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.test.tabbar.style" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="background">#00ff00</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.test.ActionBar.TabBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="background">#00ff00</item>
</style>
```

You need to set it twice because of HoneyComb and pre-HoneyComb devices. To use the new theme you will also need to add the following into the application tag in the manifest file.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.test"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by checking out this other SO post: [Android ActionBar Tab Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585002/android-actionbar-tab-color)  However, it seems like you can only set the whole background color & color of the bottom bar, not the color of each tab.

Otherwise, if you want to go old-skool, you could use a TabHost instead of an ActionBar.  This'll allow you to set colors for each specific tab, and you should be able to style them similarly to the very 4.2ish ActionBar.  'Tis very simple:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(TAB_1_INDEX).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_1_inactive);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(TAB_2_INDEX).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_2_inactive);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(TAB_3_INDEX).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_3_inactive);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundResource(activeTabShape[pos]);
```

Comment: i'm actually planning to set the whole background to my tab. not per item/tab. :)

Comment: Ah cool, then that SO page I referenced has a lot of good resources.  You should check those out and then up-vote the one you like. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking to use [ActionBar.Tab setCustomView (View view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#setCustomView%28android.view.View%29)