# how to set TextView on ImageView in Android

Tags: android

i'm at learning stage of android. i want to set TextView on ImageView. i'm not getting point. I'll be thankful. Here's is my XML code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="380dp"       
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"    
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/wf" />


    <TextView
   // what should i add here so that it can be visible on image view//
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to put a TextView in fromt of an ImageView? You can't do this simply with a LinearLayout because this puts all views in a line side by side.

Comment: This does not make sense. A view cannot be both a textview and an imageview. If you want to combine views, you can use a viewgroup.

Comment: not in front of image view while i want to set TextView on ImageView...?

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: i have added a picture through ImageView. now i want some text on same picture which will be randomly change...how can i add/set TextView over said picture....??hope u got it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding text to ImageView in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404582/adding-text-to-imageview-in-android)

Comment: `FrameLayout` enables you to overlay views.

Comment: Simon, can you write some code for me...i'll be thankful to you dear

Comment: Sorry, but no.  StackOverflow doesn't work like that.  You ask a question, people answer it (if it's on topic).  There are hundreds of tutorials on the web, all easily found with Google.

Comment: Simon, Thanks for your suggestion..i've used FrameLayout as per your suggestion so finally got the point..Sorry if u did mind...Actually i'm very very beginner..anyway thanks for your cooperation..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all, Finally i got solution. i used FrameLayout to handle it.

Here is the code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="380dp"       
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"    
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/wf" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like a photo caption therefore the Best way you can achieve that is by using a relative layout and your .xml layout would look like:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Take note of the property of the textView

```
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
```

That is the key.
If for any reason you prefer a linearlayout as the main layout , you can nest a relative layout in a table -row (or another linear layout) which is nested in the main linear layout

i hope that isnt complicating

PS:this is a beginner's advice

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `RelativeLayout` as a parent, `ImageView` as the first child element and `TextView` as the second child element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RelativeLayout like this :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="380dp"       
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"    
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/wf" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```