# how to add text with highlight color background it to ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview, android-xml

I trying to add text with highlight color to ImageView, I doing some search and I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8271134/4205927) and I applied it successfully, but I need to make background highlight of text with color black like this in image

[destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVRkS.jpg)

the current XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/postImage"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/postImage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/postImage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/postImage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/postImage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/postImage"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Need set background color for Textview

Comment: @LiemVo already color set as white

Comment: I mean `android:background`  not `android:textColor` of textView. The value of the background can be a color, drawable,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is : Add background color to text view and set alpha value based on transparency.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lasdfjsdfjlsdkfj"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/image"
        android:alpha="0.5"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Adjust the alpha value for the amount of transparency you want. Value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ConstraintLayout`. You also need to create `drawable` file

Your layout should look like;

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/postImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_headset"/>


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/postTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/border_bottom_rounded"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:text="title"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Your drawable file (`border_bottom_rounded`) should be like;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#A9000000"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#A9000000" />
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: after applied this, I see blank page!, Is ConstraintLayout working normally with GridLayoutManager ?

Comment: did you get any log? I think it works with GridLayoutManager normally.

Comment: no, I just copied the whole layout, I'll trying this drawable style with current RelativeLayout maybe works

Answer (score 0):

you can use the both options suggests by @Ergin Ersoy and @Ravi

After creating drawable file `(border_bottom_rounded)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#A9000000"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#A9000000" />
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

set it as backgrounf of TextView, also I would suggest to make `android:alpha="1"` insted of 0.5 to make the text clear

**the full result xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/postImage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/postImage"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/postImage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/postImage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/postImage"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom_rounded"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```