# Canvas.drawText Right to Left in Java

Tags: java, canvas, right-to-left

How can I output text Right to Left (i.e. in reverse order) using Canvas.drawText ? Is there a way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this out: [How to draw RTL text (Arabic) onto a Bitmap and have it ordered properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417503/how-to-draw-rtl-text-arabic-onto-a-bitmap-and-have-it-ordered-properly)

Comment: But how do you "use manual BiDi"? In other words, assuming I can detect that I should be going to right to left, how do I tell the drawText function to output the text in reverse?

Comment: And no solution on the link too

Answer (score 1):

Set `Paint.Align` property in your `textPaint` object, if you set it RIGHT -- The text is drawn to the left of the x,y origin:

```
textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
canvas.drawText("your text here", getRight(), getY()/2, textPaint);
```

Comment: Right-aligned text is not the same thing as right-to-left text.